# Should an installed PWA on iPhone be opening in Safari?

Tags: iphone, safari, progressive-web-apps

My PWA is installing fine via Chrome on Android devices - when I open the installed app it opens as an app, not in a browser.

On iPhone when I add my PWA to the home screen, hitting the app icon opens the app in Safari, not it's own app (and not in standalone mode). Is this normal behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I analyzed the PWA in Lighthouse in Chrome's Dev tools and found issues with the manifest file. Fixed them and now it installs fine.